# Specific associated domains for multiple targets in the Xcode project

Tags: xcode, ios-universal-links, xcode-project, associated-domains

I have several targets in Xcode. Everytime I change the domains in the target`s setting:
Targets - Target name - Capabilities - Associated Domains

then this change is propagated also to the setting of the other targets.

To me it seems like a bug in Xcode.

Xcode version: 10.0 (10A255)

Answer (score 28):

By default there is only one file at which all target settings point to: project.entitlements

There is a text field in the target build settings **Code Signing Entitlements** with a path that can be updated. For each target the path can be different.